How can I capture XDND information while dragging files between different directories in unbuntu
I wrote a demo to capture XDND type messages for dragging files between  folders in UBUNTU22.04. But I found that even though I set the mask for all message types, I still couldn't catch messages from the Client Message type when I was dragging files from one directory to another.
Here is my code, which can be compiled directly from Downloads folder(It`s Important as I implied based on the folder , see it in my code :D ) to others  on uruntu22-64bits
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef unsigned int ATOM;
#define Bool int
#define Status int
#define True 1
#define False 0

#define TRUE 1
#define FALE 0
static  Atom      XdndVersion= (Atom)3;

static  Atom      XdndAware;
static  Atom      XdndSelection;
static  Atom      XdndEnter;
static  Atom      XdndLeave;
static  Atom      XdndPosition;
static  Atom      XdndDrop;
static  Atom      XdndFinished;
static  Atom      XdndStatus;
static  Atom      XdndActionCopy;
static  Atom      XdndActionMove;
static  Atom      XdndActionLink;
static  Atom      XdndActionAsk;
static  Atom      XdndActionPrivate;
static  Atom      XdndTypeList;
static  Atom      XdndTextUriList;
static  Atom      XdndSelectionAtom;

static  Window    xdndSourceWindow= 0;
static  Atom     *xdndTypeList= 0;
static  int   xdndWillAccept= 0;

#define xdndEnter_sourceWindow(evt)     ( (evt)->data.l[0])
#define xdndEnter_version(evt)          ( (evt)->data.l[1] >> 24)
#define xdndEnter_hasThreeTypes(evt)        (((evt)->data.l[1] & 0x1UL) == 0)
#define xdndEnter_typeAt(evt, idx)      ( (evt)->data.l[2 + (idx)])

#define xdndPosition_sourceWindow(evt)      ((Window)((evt)->data.l[0]))
#define xdndPosition_rootX(evt)         ((evt)->data.l[2] >> 16)
#define xdndPosition_rootY(evt)         ((evt)->data.l[2] & 0xffffUL)
#define xdndPosition_action(evt)        ((Atom)((evt)->data.l[4]))

#define xdndStatus_targetWindow(evt)        ((evt)->data.l[0])
#define xdndStatus_setWillAccept(evt, b)    ((evt)->data.l[1]= (((evt)->data.l[1] & ~1UL) | ((b) ? 1 : 0)))
#define xdndStatus_setWantPosition(evt, b)  ((evt)->data.l[1]= (((evt)->data.l[1] & ~2UL) | ((b) ? 2 : 0)))
#define xdndStatus_action(evt)          ((evt)->data.l[4])

#define xdndDrop_sourceWindow(evt)      ((Window)((evt)->data.l[0]))
#define xdndDrop_time(evt)          ((evt)->data.l[2])

#define xdndFinished_targetWindow(evt)      ((evt)->data.l[0])

enum XdndState {
  XdndStateIdle,
  XdndStateEntered,
  XdndStateTracking
};
static enum XdndState xdndState= XdndStateIdle;

struct xdndatom {
  Atom  atom;
  char *name;
};

 struct FullLinuxWindowAttributes
{
    unsigned int sizeof_FullLinuxWindowAttributes;
    char windowName[512];
    int root_x_return;
    int root_y_return;
    int win_x_return;
    int win_y_return;
    
    char typeof_currentX11Window[32];
    char* currentX11Window;
    unsigned int sizeof_CurrentX11Window;
    
    char typeof_xWindowAttributes[32];
    char* xWindowAttributes;
    unsigned int sizeof_xWindowAttributes;
    char attributes[2048][32];
    char reservedData[512]; 
};

static struct xdndatom xdndatoms[] = {
  { 0, "XdndAware"                },
  { 0, "XdndSelection"            },
  { 0, "XdndEnter"                },
  { 0, "XdndLeave"                },
  { 0, "XdndPosition"             },
  { 0, "XdndDrop"                 },
  { 0, "XdndFinished"             },
  { 0, "XdndStatus"               },
  { 0, "XdndActionCopy"           },
  { 0, "XdndActionMove"           },
  { 0, "XdndActionLink"           },
  { 0, "XdndActionAsk"            },
  { 0, "XdndActionPrivate"        },
  { 0, "XdndTypeList"             },
  { 0, "XdndActionList"           },
  { 0, "XdndActionDescription"    },
  { 0, "text/uri-list"            },
  { 0, "UTF8_STRING"              },
  { 0, "COMPOUND_TEXT"            },
  { 0, "TEXT"                     },
  { 0, "STRING"                   },
  { 0, "text/plain;charset=utf-8" },
  { 0, "text/plain"               }
};
char** uxDropFileNames;
static  Atom      XdndTypeList;
static  Atom      XdndTextUriList;
  Display* stDisplay ; 
  Window stParent;
void dndInitialise(void)
{

  XdndAware=         XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndAware", False);
  XdndSelection=     XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndSelection", False);
  XdndEnter=         XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndEnter", False);
  XdndLeave=         XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndLeave", False);
  XdndPosition=      XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndPosition", False);
  XdndDrop=      XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndDrop", False);
  XdndFinished=      XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndFinished", False);
  XdndStatus=        XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndStatus", False);
  XdndActionCopy=    XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionCopy", False);
  XdndActionMove=    XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionMove", False);
  XdndActionLink=    XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionLink", False);
  XdndActionAsk=     XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionAsk", False);
  XdndActionPrivate=     XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionPrivate", False);
  XdndTypeList=      XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndTypeList", False);
  XdndTextUriList=   XInternAtom(stDisplay, "text/uri-list", False);
  XdndSelectionAtom=     XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndSqueakSelection", False);

  XChangeProperty(stDisplay, stParent, XdndAware, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&XdndVersion, 1);
}
static const char *xdnd_get_atom_name(Atom atom)
{
  int i;
  char *name = "Unregistered Xdnd Atom";
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(xdndatoms) / sizeof(struct xdndatom); i++)
  {
    if(xdndatoms[i].atom == atom)
    {
      name = xdndatoms[i].name;
      break;
    }
  }
  return name;
}
static void *xcalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
  void *ptr= calloc(nmemb, size);
  if (!ptr)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  return ptr;
}
static void dndGetTypeList(XClientMessageEvent *evt)
{
    if(!stDisplay)
        return ;

    if (xdndTypeList)
    {
        free(xdndTypeList);
        xdndTypeList= 0;
    }

  xdndWillAccept= 0;

    if (xdndEnter_hasThreeTypes(evt))
    {
        int i;
        printf("  3 types\n");
        xdndTypeList= (Atom *)xcalloc(3 + 1, sizeof(Atom));
        for (i= 0;  i <  3;  ++i)
            xdndTypeList[i]= xdndEnter_typeAt(evt, i);
        xdndTypeList[3]= 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Atom type, *atoms;
        int format;
        unsigned long i, count, remaining;
        unsigned char *data= 0;

        XGetWindowProperty(stDisplay, xdndSourceWindow, XdndTypeList, 0, 0x8000000L, False, XA_ATOM,
             &type, &format, &count, &remaining, &data);

        if ((type != XA_ATOM) || (format != 32) || (count == 0) || !data)
        {
        if (data) XFree(data);
        fprintf(stderr, "XGetWindowProperty failed in xdndGetTypeList\n");
        return;
        }

        xdndTypeList= (Atom *)xcalloc(count + 1, sizeof(Atom));
        atoms= (Atom *)data;
        for (i= 0;  i < count;  ++i)
            xdndTypeList[i]= atoms[i];
        xdndTypeList[count]= 0;
        XFree(data);
        printf("  %ld types\n", count);
    }

  /* We only accept filenames (MIME type "text/uri-list"). */
    {
        int i;
        for (i= 0;  xdndTypeList[i];  ++i)
        {
            printf("  type %d == %ld %s\n", i, xdndTypeList[i], XGetAtomName(stDisplay, xdndTypeList[i]));
            if (XdndTextUriList == xdndTypeList[i])
                xdndWillAccept= 1;
        }
    }
}
static void dndEnter(XClientMessageEvent *evt)
{
  printf( "dndEnter\n");
  if (xdndEnter_version(evt) < 3)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "xdnd: protocol version %ld not supported\n", xdndEnter_version(evt));
      return;
    }
  Window xdndSourceWindow= xdndEnter_sourceWindow(evt);
  dndGetTypeList(evt);
  xdndState= XdndStateEntered;
}
static void dndSendFinished(Window target)
{
    XClientMessageEvent evt;
    memset (&evt, 0, sizeof(evt));

    evt.type         = ClientMessage;
    evt.display      = stDisplay;
    evt.window       = xdndSourceWindow;
    evt.message_type = XdndFinished;
    evt.format       = 32;

    xdndFinished_targetWindow(&evt)= target;

    XSendEvent(stDisplay, xdndSourceWindow, 0, 0, (XEvent *)&evt);

    printf( "sent finished to %ld\n", xdndSourceWindow);
}
static void dndLeave(XClientMessageEvent *evt)
{
    printf("dndLeave\n");
    //recordDragEvent(DragLeave, 1);
    xdndState= XdndStateIdle;
}
static void dndGetSelection(Window owner, Atom property)
{
    unsigned long remaining;
    unsigned char *data= 0;
    Atom actual;
    int format;
    unsigned long count;

    if (Success != XGetWindowProperty(stDisplay, owner, property, 0, 65536, 1, AnyPropertyType,
                        &actual, &format, &count, &remaining, &data))
        fprintf(stderr, "dndGetSelection: XGetWindowProperty failed\n");
    else if (remaining)
        /* a little violent perhaps */
        fprintf(stderr, "dndGetSelection: XGetWindowProperty has more than 64K (why?)\n");
    else
    {
        char *tokens= data;
        char *item= 0;
        while ((item= strtok(tokens, "\n\r")))
        {
            printf("got URI <%s>\n", item);
            if (!strncmp(item, "file:", 5))     /*** xxx BOGUS -- just while image is broken ***/
            {
            /* if (uxDropFileCount)
                uxDropFileNames= (char **)xrealloc(uxDropFileNames, (uxDropFileCount + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            else
                uxDropFileNames= (char **)xcalloc(1, sizeof(char *));
                uxDropFileNames[uxDropFileCount++]= uri2string(item);*/
            }
        tokens= 0;
        }
        //if (uxDropFileCount)
                //recordDragEvent(DragDrop, uxDropFileCount);
        //printf("+++ DROP %d\n", uxDropFileCount);
    }
    XFree(data);
}

int dndHandleSelectionNotify(XSelectionEvent *evt)
{
  if (evt->property == XdndSelectionAtom)
    {
      dndGetSelection(evt->requestor, evt->property);
      dndSendFinished(evt->requestor);
      dndLeave((XClientMessageEvent *)evt);
      return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}

int dndHandleClientMessage(XClientMessageEvent *evt)
{
    int handled= 1;
    Atom type= evt->message_type;
    printf("dndHandleClientMessage\n");
    if(type == XdndEnter)    dndEnter(evt);
    /*else if (type == XdndPosition) dndPosition(evt);
    else if (type == XdndDrop)   dndDrop(evt);
    else if (type == XdndLeave)  dndLeave(evt);*/
    else     handled= 0;
    return handled;
}

static void run(Window checkWindow)
{
    while (1)
    {
        XEvent evt;
        long event_mask= ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask
                        | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask
                        | PointerMotionMask
                        | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask | ExposureMask;
        event_mask = 0x00ffffff;
        XSelectInput(stDisplay,checkWindow,event_mask);

        XWindowEvent (stDisplay,checkWindow, event_mask,&evt);
        printf ("evt.type: %d\n",evt.type);
        switch (evt.type)
        {

            case MotionNotify:  printf("MotionNotify\n");           break;
            case EnterNotify:   printf("EnterNotify\n");            break;
            case LeaveNotify:   printf("LeaveNotify\n");            break;
            case ButtonPress:   printf("ButtonPress\n");            break;
            case ButtonRelease: printf("ButtonRelease\n");          break;
            case KeyPress:      printf("KeyPress\n");               break;
            case KeyRelease:    printf("KeyRelease\n");             break;
            case SelectionClear:    printf("SelectionClear\n");         break;
            case SelectionRequest:  printf("SelectionRequest\n");           break;
            case PropertyNotify:    printf("PropertyNotify\n");         break;
            case Expose:        printf("Expose\n");             break;
            case MapNotify:     printf("MapNotify\n");              break;
            case UnmapNotify:   printf("UnmapNotify\n");            break;
            case ConfigureNotify:   printf("ConfigureNotify\n");            break;
            case MappingNotify: printf("MappingNotify\n");          break;
            case ClientMessage: 
            {
                printf("ClientMessage\n");  
                dndHandleClientMessage(&evt.xclient);       
                break;
            }
            case SelectionNotify:   
            {
                printf("SelectionNotify\n");    
                dndHandleSelectionNotify(&evt.xselection);  
                break;
            }
            default:        printf("unknown event type %d\n", evt.type);    break;
        }
    }
}
int get_linux_window_info(struct FullLinuxWindowAttributes* outPutAttributes)
{
    int root_x_return;
    int root_y_return;
    int win_x_return;
    int win_y_return;
    int returnValue= 0;
    //Display* stDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL); 
    if(!stDisplay)
        return -1;
    XWindowAttributes xWindowAttributes;
    Window w;
    Window root_window = DefaultRootWindow(stDisplay);
    Window root_return;
    Window parent_return;
    Window child_window;
    Window* child_window_spec = NULL;
    ATOM XdndPositionAtom ;
    ATOM XdndDropAtom ;
    ATOM XdndActionCopyAtom ;
    ATOM XdndStatusAtom ;
    ATOM XdndFinishedAtom;
    ATOM XdndAware;
    XEvent event;
    unsigned long type, len, remain =0;
    int form = 0;
    unsigned char *listAttribute;
    
    unsigned int windowNum = 0;
    unsigned int mask;
    if(outPutAttributes)
        outPutAttributes = malloc(sizeof(XWindowAttributes));
    if(!outPutAttributes)
        return -1;
    
    returnValue = XQueryPointer(stDisplay, root_window, &root_window, &child_window, \
        &root_x_return, &root_y_return, \
        &win_x_return, &win_y_return, &mask);

    returnValue = XQueryTree(stDisplay, root_window, &root_window, &parent_return, &child_window_spec, &windowNum);
    if(windowNum>0)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < windowNum; ++i) 
        {
            XGetWindowAttributes(stDisplay, child_window_spec[i], &xWindowAttributes);
            if (xWindowAttributes.map_state == 2) 
            { // IsViewable
                char* buffer = NULL;
                // 
                XFetchName(stDisplay, child_window_spec[i], &buffer);

                // 
                printf("# %d :(attrs.x %d : attrs.y %d attrs.width %d , attrs.height %d ) name %s \n", \
                            i , xWindowAttributes.x , xWindowAttributes.y ,  \
                            xWindowAttributes.width , xWindowAttributes.height , buffer) ;
                // 
                outPutAttributes->sizeof_FullLinuxWindowAttributes = sizeof(struct FullLinuxWindowAttributes);
                if(buffer) 
                    memcpy(outPutAttributes->windowName,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                outPutAttributes->root_x_return = root_x_return;
                outPutAttributes->root_y_return = root_y_return;
                outPutAttributes->win_x_return = win_x_return;
                outPutAttributes->win_y_return = win_y_return;

                strcpy(outPutAttributes->typeof_currentX11Window,"Window");
                memcpy(&(outPutAttributes->currentX11Window),&child_window_spec[i],sizeof(Window) );
                outPutAttributes->sizeof_CurrentX11Window = sizeof(Window);

                strcpy(outPutAttributes->typeof_xWindowAttributes,"XWindowAttributes");
                memcpy(&(outPutAttributes->xWindowAttributes),&xWindowAttributes,sizeof(XWindowAttributes) );
                outPutAttributes->sizeof_xWindowAttributes = sizeof(XWindowAttributes);
                XdndAware = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndAware", True);
                
                /*XdndPositionAtom = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndPosition", True);
                XdndDropAtom = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndDrop", True);
                XdndActionCopyAtom = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndActionCopy", True);
                XdndStatusAtom = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndStatus", True);
                XdndFinishedAtom = XInternAtom(stDisplay, "XdndFinished", True);*/
                
                /*xclipboard*/
                
                if(buffer==NULL)
                    continue;
                if(strcmp(buffer,"Downloads")==0)
                {
                   
                    int result =  XGetWindowProperty( stDisplay, child_window_spec[i], XdndAware,
                            0, 65535, False, AnyPropertyType, &type, &form, &len, &remain,&listAttribute );   
                    if(type != None && result== Success)
                    {
                        result =  XGetWindowProperty( stDisplay, child_window_spec[i], XdndAware,
                            0, remain, False, AnyPropertyType, &type, &form, &len, &remain,&listAttribute );
                        if(type != None && result== Success)
                        {
                            printf("type %ld, form %d, len %ld, remain %ld \n",type, form, len, remain); 
                            ATOM tempAtom ;
                            memcpy (&tempAtom,listAttribute,4);
                            tempAtom = tempAtom & 0xFF;
                            printf("tempAtom %lu\n",(unsigned long)tempAtom);
                            /*char* tempAtomName = XGetAtomName(stDisplay,tempAtom);
                            if(tempAtomName)
                            printf("tempAtomName %s \n",tempAtomName); */
                            run(child_window_spec[i]);
                            
                        } 
                        
                    }
                }
                XFree(buffer);
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}



int select_file()
{
    struct FullLinuxWindowAttributes outPutAttributes;
    get_linux_window_info(&outPutAttributes);
}
void main()
{
    stDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL); 
    stParent = DefaultRootWindow(stDisplay);
    dndInitialise();
    {
        //run(stParent);
        struct FullLinuxWindowAttributes outPutAttributes;
        get_linux_window_info(&outPutAttributes);
    }
    //select_file();
}



I'm a little unsure if X11 doesn't use the XDND protocol at all when dragging files between ubuntu folders, but the question is, how does x11 sense the purpose of the dropback form to support this feature? And how to get the source file path and destination path during the drag and drop process?

I don't understand the relevance of the qt tag, but, most importantly, it's unclear if the "dragging between folders" refers to folder items in one specific file manager window/contents or not. I don't know the X protocol that much, but as far as I know, if you're dealing with dnd within the same application window (the file manager) there's no guarantee that there would be any X notification at all. In fact, the application may just do what it "prefers" with the drag event, including handling it but not managing it.

@musicamante In my understanding QT is also a GUI framework based on the X protocol, so the tag also comes with it. I tried dragging files between zip file archivers, wine, and just directories , these test case  are all without triggering the XDND protocol trace, that`s really  confusing.

Qt is a very wide toolkit that can also use the X protocol under certain circumstances. In fact: 1. Qt can be used without any display capability, because it's not just a UI framework; 2. X and *nix in general (and any other platform) allow using any UI toolkit, so targeting or restricting this to Qt is pointless; 3. there are plenty of different UI toolkits that can be used in X (and anybody can create their own on any platform); adding the Qt tag just because it can use X is pointless: what about adding Gtk (the Ubuntu standard), Motif, Kivy and many others as well? »

» Specifying a tag means that the question is targeted to that language/toolkit/etc tag, but dnd is not toolkit specific. As said, each X "client" may decide to implement X specific server calls: "zip file archivers", wine programs or "directories" (again, it's not clear if you're talking about the "desktop" or a file manager) are clients, they are not unique identifiers to a specific "target object" like a "directory", which is just an abstraction. The X client (the program, or even the window/desktop manager) may decide to provide such notifications, but that's not a requirement. »

» It seems like you expect that "anything" would eventually notify a dnd target as a file or folder, but that's just your expectation based on an ambiguous and superficial assumptions. The "targets" you mentioned above are, in fact, actual programs (aka, X clients) that may decide to do whatever they want with the dnd events, including handling but still ignoring them. I could write a program that accepts a dragged or dropped "file" and I don't need to notify X what I'm doing with it, including (but not excluding) that I'd deal with it as it was dropped on a directory or not.

So, do you have any suggestions for the capture of a program dragging files into the file manager? For example, what events should I try to capture, and how do I get the source and destination paths in the drag process? Thank you very much.

Sorry but I thought that my explanation above was clear enough: there is no absolute way to know anything about the source or destination of a drag&drop operation. The origin and target programs may provide that information, but it's not an absolute requirement. Meaning that, unless you are certain about program capabilities of both parts, you can only assume that you'll never know nothing to begin with.

Thank you very much for your valuable advice, if we narrow the scope a little bit, let's say a program X, drag and drop its files into the UBUNTU "File folder", we can simplify a little bit more, do not consider the source file path name problem, only consider the destination directory name, for the implementation of this feature, Do you have any experience or advice to offer me? Thank you again for your guidance.

As already said, a client is not required to provide such info. Besides, it's still unclear what you mean by "File folder": a file manager? then which one? is it the desktop? and how does the desktop/window manager deal with it? If you can't make a distinction between these, then you have a more important issue, as there are very different implementation layers in play, and you can't ignore such aspects. You're trying to get a distinction that is completely optional: a target could accept a dnd event no matter its contents or what it'd do with it. And X must not know anything about it.
